# XAMPP - change URL for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, xampp

how can i make Laravel project run on `http://localhost` instead of `http://localhost/project-name/public/` using `xampp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom domain on your windows machine by configuring xampp and windows.

1. Go to `xampp\apache\conf\extra` folder ,
2. Open the file called `httpd-vhosts.conf` and add the following code block
   and save :

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project-name\public"
>     ServerName  myproject.dv
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

3. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` , open the file called
   `hosts`.
4. Add your domain name there like this

   `127.0.0.1       myproject.dv`
5. Save the file (you need admin permission to save this file)
6. Restart your xampp
7. Go to the browser and access your project there `http://myproject.dv`